# Using syntax highligher with code tag?

Tags: php, html, syntax-highlighting

I get some html output as:

```
<div class="test-code">    
   <pre>
       <code>
          <?php echo "hello world"; ?>
       </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Is it possible to use any basic PHP syntax highlighter with above HTML without changing anything in above syntax? I have been searching, but most of the syntax highlighters seems to be pretty advanced and require to define the code class in the `pre` (eg. `pre class="php"`).

Edit: I am looking for any Javascript/jQuery based syntax highlight which automatically assumes that any code inside the `<code>` is a PHP code and highlights it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would certainly recommend [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

It normally auto-detects the language being written in the code block.

Common usage is as follows:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
  <code>
// your code here
  </code>
</pre>
```

**NOTE:** Prettify takes tabs literally. Do not tab your code within the block, but rather use spaces.

Comment: Thanks but I think it requires to define the pre class. For example this wont work. `<pre>..</pre>`.

Comment: The README has a lot of good information in it: http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Comment: I've just had good luck with the `<pre class="prettyprint"><code></code></pre>` convention.

Answer (score 2):

There's [`highlight_string()`](http://php.net/highlight_string) but that really only highlights the PHP code and wraps everything else in `<code>` tags

```
<?php

$markup = <<<MARKUP
<div class="test-code">    
   <pre>
       <code>
          <?php echo "hello world"; ?>
       </code>
    </pre>
</div>
MARKUP;

highlight_string($markup);
```

Output: http://codepad.org/qnLGqP7N

As far as I know, the method you mentioned is used by javascript highlighters.

Comment: +1 I was writing this exact same thing, complete with codepad example and HEREDOC string. One difference: `highlight_string()` outputs (not returns) by default, so you don't need `echo`. In fact, `echo` results in a stray "1" in your output.

Comment: @Wiseguy Thanks, didn't catch the return/print thing

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for some javascript based highlighter which automatically highlights the code inside the `<code>` tag.

Comment: @user966582 You tagged the question with PHP and not javascript.

Comment: @MikeB Sorry If my question wasnt clear. I meant I want to highlight the PHP code wrapped in the `<code>` using some javascript based syntax highlighter (eg. prettify) in which I don't need to define the class for the `<pre> or <code>`